Can site browsing data be exported?
I'm new to Salesforce Commerce Cloud, so I apologize if this question has answers elsewhere.  I tried searching for this, and I couldn't find anything.
In Salesforce Commerce Cloud, is there a way to export visitor browsing data?  I want to be able to export visitor traffic and/or events from SFCC into a data warehouse where I can link user sessions to other corresponding data -- such as orders.  From my searching, I've found ways to export other types of objects -- such as accounts -- but I haven't been able to find a way to export browsing data.

This sounds like a use case for Data Cloud.
Check more (marketing) information about it at https://www.salesforce.com/eu/data/
Also the following trailhead module
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/b2c-cdp-for-commerce
and technical documentation
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_commerce_cloud_connector.htm&type=5

For now, the reports and dashboards containing this data are "closed" off. However, the 2024 Roadmap states that a JDBC connector will be made available to export the data to your own warehouse.
Note: The actual release date I can not provide, also no public slides or text about this is available.
